# What could be the reason for background-image to not work in my code

Tags: html, css

I have tried applying it to the other website and it worked everywhere but in my code, and i don't know what could be the issue, i've checked the file path and it was correct and i even tried links (like in this situation) and it still didnt work no matter how i try applying it, it doesn't work on this project.
Also, is it okay to use percentages as an unit for paddings?

HTML AND CSS:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 7%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 13vh;
}

.logo-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 2.7;
    }
    
    .logo {
        margin: 5px;
    }

 .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-around;

}

nav {
flex: 1;
}

.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links > li {
    padding-right: 15%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.slide {
    background-image: url('https://media3.giphy.com/media/1AgjJa5aX1vmIvx8Zr/giphy.gif');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css">
    <title>Elrond</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="/Images/elrond-egld-egld-logo.png" alt="elrond" style="height: 6.5vh;">
                <h3 class="logo">elrond</h3>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </nav>
    </header>

<main>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="inner">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE: IGNORE THE IMAGES THAT AREN'T LOADING, FOCUS ON THE .slide CLASS**
Load the website in full screen because i still didn't make it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Your divs have no width or height, so the background image does not have space to take up.

```
.inner {
   height: 100px; 
   width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your .slide class doesn't have height set yet. In html/css div covers the width by default but it has no height. background-image don't determine the height property as oppose to inner nodes. For your code to work you must set height to your .slide class or may be just put your background-image into .wrapper class.
Edit: Also since you .wrapper container is flex you will need to specify flex:1 property inside your .slide class.

Answer (score 0):

your .inner class should get a height and width to be shown.
or instead you can give .wrapper a background-image

Answer (score 0):

Image is not displaying due to the fact you are not using `width`.Add `width:100%;`
with your `slide` class.Also if you don't want to repeat background then also use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` with `slide` class. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
.slide {
            background-image: url('https://media3.giphy.com/media/1AgjJa5aX1vmIvx8Zr/giphy.gif');
            width:100%;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
```

Comment: Also you can set width of your own choice.

Answer (score 0):

I ran you code you have images got fetched but did not render due to you did not specify the div width and height

````css
    .slide{height:300px;
       width:500px;
       background-image:url("YOUR-IMAGE-LINK(EITHER LOCAL OR HTTP://");
}```
````